# How can I print 2 pages per sheet on word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, printer

I tried setting the printer to two pages per sheet but it did not come out the way I expected the printer indeed did print 2 pages but not on the long side, it printed 2 pages but on the short side making the word size smaller and taking up half the space of 1 page making it difficult to read. How can I print 2 pages on the longer side so that the words and diagrams will be more legible for me to read?

Comment: This depends on your printer. Check the printer settings/preferences from the print dialog and configure it to print the way you want.

Comment: I'm not sure what you men by long and short sides. If you print 2 pages on the same side, then each page can only take up half a sheet; hence it's smaller. Word will not squash the page vertically only, as that would distort the page. Or, do you mean one page on each SIDE of the sheet (duplexing)? That depends on your printer and driver. Some can, others cannot.

Answer (score 0):

You could see if your printer support this directly in its driver. Go to the Windows Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Devices and Printers.
Right mouse click your printer and select Printer Properties.
There you have to see in the preferences, Advanced or Device settings if you have this setting.

Another option is to use a commercial solution like [Print&Share](http://www.printandshare.info) to do this.
In Print&Share you first create a new profile with a printer channel. Than in the channel configuration of the printer channel you can modify the setting "Pages on 1 sheet" and click OK to close the configuration.

*Note: I'm affiliated with this software.*

Comment: I said "commercial solution", thus metioning that it isn't free. Also added more info on how to configure it.